# getInt() SharedPreferences android error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences peepsScores= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(GamePlayFirst.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =peepsScores.edit();

editor.putInt("userScore1", zero);
editor.putInt("userScore2", zero);
editor.putInt("userScore3", zero);
editor.putInt("userScore4", zero);
editor.putInt("userScore5", zero);
editor.putInt("userScore6", zero);
editor.putInt("userScore7", zero);
editor.putInt("userScore8", zero);
editor.commit();

SharedPreferences peepsScores = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
//tryed this
int userScore1 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore1","u");
//tryed this
userScore2 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore2","0");
//and tryed this
String userScore3 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore3","0");
String userScore4 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore4","0");
String userScore5 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore5","0");
String userScore6 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore6","0");
String userScore7 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore7","0");
String userScore8 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore8","0");
```

the getint method is underlined no matter what random things i change and then if i delete the first line of the recieving class peepScore is underlined im been on android dev webiste this website and all over google everything says its as easy as getInt what am i doing wrong

Ill try to figure out adding later i guess when i finaly get this im posting this for all newbs like me to see lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this.

```
int userScore1 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore1",0);
```

> When you use getInt then you have to return integer value if your
>   value is not set in shared preference.

Comment: wow thank you so much it was the "" marks just needed removed your awsome

Comment: @user1777400 do not forget to accept answer . so other people can use it.

Comment: nevermind figured that out thanks you have no idea how much time i wasted on that lol

Comment: Cool. I don't even know that